# Why is not allowing spread operator in React Native component property assignment a performance optimization?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In a React Native component if the spread operator is used in the props assignment, an error, "In this environment the target of assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant." is thrown.

For example, in render function

```
const { style } = props;
  return (
    <View style={{borderWidth: 1, ...style}}>
```

gives[image]

meanwhile

```
const { style } = props;
  return (
    <View style={{borderWidth: 1, paddingLeft: 1}}>
```

works. Why does the spread syntax affect performance?

Comment: Have you tried doing this in an array, like: `<View style={[{paddingLeft:1}, ...style]}>`?

Comment: hmm, wouldn't expect that to work because https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html says 'In React, inline styles are [...] specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of the style name [...].'

Comment: but just tried it and it works! strangeness.

Answer (score 5):

Actually it turns out to be Number when the style property passed to the child component if you use `StyleSheet.create()`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the accepted answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020404/error-when-creating-new-object-from-existing-one-using-in-this-environmen).
You cannot use `...` in a style definition because StyleSheet.create() doesn't return a regular javascript object.

However, you can use `...` during the initialization of a `StyleSheet`, i.e.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        top:null,
    }
})
```

To solve your issue, you should use flatten:

```
const { style } = props;
StyleSheet.flatten([style, {borderWidth: 1}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Change things like

```
active && 'foo'
```

to

```
active ? 'foo' : ''
```

react native hates `&&` assignment.
I think it’s a bug in packager somewhere deep.