# Error when creating new object from existing one using `...`: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my React Native app, I have a situation where one particular child of a component that I `render` should receive either a green or red `borderColor`.

Now, I don't want to create two separate entries in my `styles` for these two situations since they only differ in the `borderColor` property.

My idea was to derive the proper style object from the ones which I have in my `styles` like so:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  amountSection: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderRadius: 3
  }
})

render() {
  const amountBorderColor = this.state.isClaim ? 'green' : 'red'
  const amountStyles = {
    ...styles.amountSection,
    borderColor: amountBorderColor
  }

  return (
    // ... apply amountStyles at appropriate component
  )
}
```

However, this code gives the following error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: In this environment the sources for assign
>   MUST be an object.This error is a performance optimization and not
>   spec compliant.

Apparently the error is hit on the line where I define `amountStyles`. Anyone knows why this happens? Is there something wrong with my syntax? I am using the `...` notation to create a new object from an existing one and add some additional properties to it.

Comment: What does `styles` look like? I think that this error is occurring because `styles.amountSection` is undefined, probably hidden by the `Stylesheet.create` factory.

Comment: `styles` is shown in the code above, or what do you mean? :) I omitted the parts that aren't relevant to my current issue, but surely `styles.amountSection` is defined as can be seen in the code sample

Comment: Are you sure? Does the `stylesheet.create` function return an object with an `amountSection` property? I'm thinking it dies not, and that that is your issue.

Comment: ahh, you might be wright though! I just recognized that `styles` is in fact not a plain javascript object but rather an instance of `StyleSheet`, so it's not possible to apply the `...` operator I guess

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As @PitaJ pointed out, my issue was that `StyleSheet.create` doesn't return a plain javascript object, so the `...` operator can't be applied.

I only want to add a solution to my original problem as well, that was to derive two different style objects from one basic one where only one property is added.

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#content) for the `StyleSheet` API indicate that the method `flatten` can be used for this:

```
const amountBorderColor = this.state.isClaim ? 'green' : 'red'
const amountStyles = StyleSheet.flatten([styles.amountSection, {borderColor: amountBorderColor}])
```

Comment: You can also use this directly on the `style` property of the JSX element, like so: `<View style={[styles.amountSection, {borderColor: this.state.isClaim ? 'green' : 'red'}]}></View>`

Answer (score 6):

It appears that the factory function does not return a JavaScript Object with the property that you need, and that the environment does not want to apply the spread operator to an undefined value. If you want to use it, pull out the object you pass to that function into a different variable.